# Multiple command only working with '&&'

Tags: windows, cmd

somehow I dont understand cmd:
Im using a script and I have something like this:

```
time /T
vwlog ...
time /T
vwlog ...
time /T
vwlog ...
time /T
```

If I start the script, the first 2 lines are working. Rest got ignored. If I add '&&' between all the commands and put this into only one line -> all of the commands are working:

```
time /T && vwlog ... && time /T && vwlog ... &&
```

Why? And how can I add the commands in different lines - and use them all? (I think it´s much easier to read a script if people are writing each command in a new line, that´s why I would like to use that way)

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/04/16/9551818.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if vwlog is a batch file then use

```
call vwlog
```